# Can we pray with make up on?

Tags: salat, cosmetics

Sometimes we do make up in some occasions or for other purposes, or in front our husband. In this case, can we pray with make up?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/72390

Comment: Also related [hanafi] : http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/36024

Comment: @0aslam0 if possible try to post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Judging from online fatawa (below), this is ordinarily acceptable.  Some concerns arose:

1. the purity of the makeup,
2. the makeup possibly invalidating wudu, and
3. the possibility of wearing makeup in front of non-mahram men.

---

Islam Q&A fatwa [Is a woman’s prayer wearing make-up considered permissible?](https://islamqa.info/en/72390):

> It should be noted that it is not permissible for a woman to wear makeup in front of non-mahram men, because she is commanded to cover her face in front of them and because wearing makeup is an adornment that leads to fitnah. **If she does that and then prays, she will have the reward for her prayer but she will have the burden of sin for tabarruj (wanton display).**

See also [Praying with nail polish](https://islamqa.info/en/20728) and [Types of make-up that affect wudoo and ghusl](https://islamqa.info/en/261).

IslamWeb fatwa [Praying wearing makeup and nail polish](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82462):

> **A woman can pray with her makeup and nail polish in her house or in any other place where no alien man can see her.** But if she needs to make Wudu or bath (Ghusul) then she has to remove only that makeup or nail polish which stops water from reaching her skin. --

See also [Praying while wearing make-up](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84705), IslamWeb.

Qibla.com fatwa [Can I pray with makeup on](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/34613), sourced from IslamQA.org:

> **You can pray with make-up on if you are sure that it is pure.** Since some make-up products contain impurities, you need to make sure that the one you put on does not contain any impure ingredients.

Qibla.com fatwa [I made wudu and applied lipstick](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33369), sourced from IslamQA.org:

> **It is valid to pray with lipstick or other make-up on, if one has applied it after having made wudu, because water would have reached the skin and lips.**

[MuftiOnline.co.za](http://muftionline.co.za/node/9921) declared someone's prayer valid after performing wudu with light makeup.

Seekers Path fatwa [[Q-ID0113] Women wearing makeup when performing Salah](http://www.seekerspath.co.uk/question-bank/purity/q-id0113-prayer-wearing-make-up/):

> **Yes, it is allowed to pray your salah whilst wearing makeup**, provided the wudu and ghusl was performed correctly.

Islam Helpline [Prayer in Makeup and nail polish](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/3417):

> **There is absolutely no harm if a believing woman wishes to offer her prayers in her full make-up**, provided she is completely covered as is the command of adornment in prayer for women.